# How do I verify if the next token in a Scanner class is empty in order to differentiate between loop conditions?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am attempting to solve a problem given to us by our professor. I need to sort through a file, `data.txt`, by appending occurrences of `;` with a blank space and occurrences of `;;` with a new line. I am having an issue determining the syntax of the *else if* clause in the *while* loop.

`Data.txt contains the following 2 lines:`

john;88;CARL;;JAFF
HELEN;MARY;;123;99

`The current code is as follows:`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Delimit {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Initiates new FileInputStream to read text document
        File f = new File("data.txt");
        // Initiates new Scanner to parse the file, and delimit at ";"
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(";");

        // Parses through each token
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            // 
            if (s.hasNext()) {
                // Prints next token followed by a space
                System.out.print(s.next() + " ");
            }
            // else if (next token is empty) {
                // Prints next token followed by a new line
                System.out.print(s.next() + "\n");
            }
        }
        s.close(); // Closes the Scanner
    }
}
```

If there is a better approach to the delimiting and replacing methods, please enlighten me! I have been trying to improve my grasp on regex and the delimitation of strings. Thanks!

Comment: you could just test `s.hasNext("")` to test if the next token is empty - but that test must be done before reading the token, that is, before the other `if`s. YOu could also just test if the value returned by `s.next()` `isExpty()` || BTW posted code is not "*appending occurrences of `;` with a blank space*", it is **replacing** - the delimiter is not included in the result of `s.nxet()`

Comment: BTW2 `System.out.print(something + "\n");` should be ` `System.out.println(something);` - `println` uses the system dependent line terminator || BTW3 comments like `// Closes the Scanner` are mostly useless, if not worse. Example if later it is changed to use something else (sockets?) and user forgot to change the comment -> can be confusing and misleading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"))) {
        scan.useDelimiter("[;\r]"); // \r as line separator in the file under Windows
        boolean addSpace = false;

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String str = scan.next().trim();

            if (str.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println();
                addSpace = false;
            } else {
                if (addSpace)
                    System.out.print(' ');

                addSpace = true;
                System.out.print(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would do away with using delimiters and just do a simple replace, `;;` -> `\n` then `;` -> `;`

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
 String line = s.nextLine ();
 while (line != null) {
    s.o.p (line.replace(";;", "\n").replace(";", "; "));
    line = s.nextLine ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a lot cleaner method, though I chose the answer @oleg.cherednik  provided as it fits better into the code structure I already created.